# URL containing periods or dots gives 403 forbidden error in PHP

Tags: php, apache, url, encoding, query-string

I want to pass a query string `dir=../../files/` in URL, but my server gave me 403 forbidden error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /example.php
>   on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have found some questions on SO, but my problem seems strange. I encoded it using [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) which results `example.php?dir=..%2F..%2Ffiles%2F`. Periods are not encoded.

I tried to replace `.` with `%2E` using [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace). The browser automatically converted to `.`. So it didn't change the result.

When I removed the second `../`(`..%2F`) from the query string, i.e., `example.php?dir=..%2Ffiles%2F`, it is okay. I don't understand why. So, my quick workaround would be to explicitly replace `.` with a recognizable character, but it doesn't make sense at all.

Any idea?

Comment: As soon as you add a slash to the url it will be treated as a path seperator not as query data.

Comment: Humm.. slash is converted to `%2F`. I think it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: did you try `base64_encode` ?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
echo $encode =  base64_encode ('../../files/');

echo '<br/>';

echo $decode = base64_decode ($encode);

//Results:

//    Li4vLi4vZmlsZXMv
//    ../../files/

?>
```

**EDIT**

This `dir=../../files/` as query string is not working because it is violating URL syntax. For more information [See Here!](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Comment: It seems working. Thank you. Could you please improve your answer why `../../` is not working while `../` is working?

Comment: "See Here!" link is now broken